# What is the best way to require modules?

Tags: javascript

I need you guys help.

When I use same modules on separate js file, What is the best way to use modules?

#### require situation

1. main.js
   (service1.js, service2.js, service3.js)
2. main.js requires services
3. Modules are not used on main.js

#### Option

1. Require modules on main.js once.
2. Require modules on different services.

Comment: requiring modules multiple times does not load them on each require so it's not an issue, rather requiring ones and passing the objects as params in each service, require the modules in services as per needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends for example 
Case 1:
If you are writing a server in node js using express and you have separate directory for routes, in that case you need to import/requires express in main server file, make some configuration, then pass exactly the same instance to your routes file.

Case 2: 
If you write a module for some utility functions so in that case you can require that module in a file which use that module. But again you don't need to require the whole module in that file you can use destructing

for example:
let {addNumbers} = require('utils')

Now it will only import a single method of that utils module

Hope it's clear to you now